# How to use string from condition1 into condition2?

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, post

I have the following code:

```
<form action='' method='POST' id='form1'>
    imdbcode :  <input type='text' id='imdbcode' name='imdbcode' /><br/>
           <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Get'/>
 </form>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
.
.
.
$title = ... ;


 echo "
 <form action='' method='POST' id='form2'>
           <input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send'/>
 </form>";
}

if(isset($_POST['Send'])){

//I WANT TO USE $Title from condition1 

} ?>
```

I want to use $title in second condition.

It prints $title in first condition! But doesn't print after closing condition!

How can I do that?

Comment: Add a hidden field to second form with `$title` value or store it in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Before you can enter the `if(isset($_POST['Send']))` 
you need submit this one:

```
echo "
<form action='' method='POST' id='form2'>
<input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send'/>
</form>";
```

but the moment you submit this, the page will be refreshed and `$_POST['submit']` will be deleted, without this variable the `$title` will not exist.

to fix this or make the `$title` value alive until the next refresh of the page. you must include the `$title` value along with the `form2`.

```
 echo "
 <form action='' method='POST' id='form2'>
 <input type='hidden' name='title' value="$title"/>
 <input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send'/>
 </form>";
```

and when the user send that form2 you can access the title by using

```
$_POST['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

As two your forms are different - there's no connection between them unless you explicitly provide it.

Simple solution can be just echo your `$title` as a hidden field in a form:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $title = ... ;
    echo "
    <form action='' method='POST' id='form2'>
           <input type='hidden' name='title' value='" . $title . "'/>
           <input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send'/>
    </form>";
}

if(isset($_POST['Send'])){
    echo $_POST['title'];
    // do other stuff
}
```

Another solution is to use sessions:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $title = ... ;
    $_SESSION['title'] = $title;
    echo "
    <form action='' method='POST' id='form2'>
           <input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send'/>
    </form>";
}

if(isset($_POST['Send'])){
    echo $_SESSION['title'];
    // do other stuff
}
```

In case of using sessions don't forget to use `session_start` and probably to unset `$_SESSION['title']` in the end of second submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='' method='POST' id='form2'>
    <input type='hidden' name='text' value='<?php echo $title; ?>
    <input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send'/>
</form>
```

Try to add a hidden input before the Send button.